# Android: How can i define Reader only for One Page in iText

Tags: android, image, pdf, itext, reader

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(fpath));
```

We can define reader in this type.This is for all PDF file. I need to define this reader only for one page. For example just for 10. page of PDF file.

We can read page by page for getting text but I need to do this for getting images .

```
TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
    strW.write(strategy.getResultantText());

    sb.append(strW.toString);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify your question: you want to extract all the images that are on one specific page in a PDF document?

Comment: Actually i want to define Reader for one specific page in a PDF.  i can say yes  for your comment.

Comment: How about replacing `for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)` by a simple `int i = 10;`?

Comment: It is not work for images like that. When we take images the method is using xrefsize. So we can not know to images in which page. So at least i want to take images just one specific. Thus i can know to image in which page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult the official documentation and search for [selectPages](https://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/selectpages). The `selectPages()` method reduces the `PdfReader` instance to the pages listed in your selection.

For instance, if you want to limit the `PdfReader` instance to page 10, you could use this line:

```
reader.selectPages("10");
```

**Update**

You claim that the above doesn't answer your question. If that is true, then please rephrase your question because I can't think of another interpretation of your question.

Maybe there's a language problem as Amedee indicates in his comment, but I think that the problem is related to some misconceptions about PDF. A PDF file is a series of objects. These objects are listed in a cross-reference table. Any software that reads a PDF needs to start at the end of the file where it will find the trailer dictionary. This trailer dictionary will refer to the root dictionary by number. The viewer will look up the object in the cross-reference table and look for the pages dictionary in the catalog. The pages dictionary contains a tree structure: the page tree. A PDF reader will move through the page tree and find a page dictionary for each page. The page dictionary will contain references to all the resources needed to render the page: the content stream(s), references to fonts, images, and so on. These objects (page dictionaries, streams, font dictionaries, etc) can be found throughout the file (at the start, in the middle, at the end). They aren't ordered in the same order as the pages. The cross-reference table knows the byte offset of each of these objects.

If you know this, you know that any question asking "I want to read only one page of a PDF by isolating a specific number of continuous bytes" is a question that reveals a deep lack of understanding of PDF.

Comment: This not exactly my request. I need to do that ; reader = reader.selectPage(10); for example. But thanks , i learned a method too.

Comment: If that is not exactly your request, then please explain what your request is. I understand that there may be a language barrier. It can help if you give examples of what you actually want, and give the code you already have written. Code is easier to write and understand than a foreign language.

Comment: @AliA Your question is wrong. I've updated my answer. Why are you asking a question that is wrong? Which problem are you trying to solve by asking a question that is wrong?

Comment: I am readin images with xrefsize. So i need to take reader for one page.

Comment: You are talking nonsense. `xrefsize` indicates the possible number of objects in the cross-reference table. You can't read images from a number. You should read the page dictionary and get the images from the XObjects in the page's resources.